# 2010 to 2016 Public Folder Migration - Error: MigrationMRSPermanentException

Tags: exchange, exchange-migration

Migrating 60gb of 2010 public folders to 2016 (on premise, 9 PF mailboxes). Mailboxes 2-9 show as "Synced" and mailbox 1 shows "Failed" with this error:

> Data migrated: 8.504 GB ‎(9,130,858,171 bytes)‎ Migration rate: 0 B
> ‎(0 bytes)‎ Error: MigrationMRSPermanentException: Error: Property
> expression "1234 Folder name" isn‎'t valid. Valid values are: Strings
> formed with characters from A to Z ‎(uppercase or lowercase)‎, digits
> from 0 to 9, !, #, $, %, &, ‎', , +, -, /, =, ?, ^, _, `, {, |, } or
> ~. One or more periods may be embedded in an alias, but each period
> should be preceded and followed by at least one of the other
> characters. Unicode characters from U+00A1 to U+00FF are also valid in
> an alias, but they will be mapped to a best-fit US-ASCII string in the
> e-mail address, which is generated from such an alias.

I have a pst backup of that folder so I have deleted it from the 2010 server.

How do I restart the migration so I can get to the 95% complete point?

I'm on Step 5 of this guide: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/collaboration/public-folders/batch-migration-from-previous-versions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchserver-2016#step-1-download-the-migration-scripts

I tried this command ( Get-PublicFolderMigrationRequest | Resume-PublicFolderMigrationRequest ) but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Hi, is there any update? Please check if the below info is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Which command did you run in EMS to start PF migration? Is the following command?

```
New-MigrationBatch -Name PFMigration -SourcePublicFolderDatabase (Get-PublicFolderDatabase -Server <Source server name>) -CSVData (Get-Content <Folder to mailbox map path> -Encoding Byte) -NotificationEmails <email addresses for migration notifications>
```

If so, please run the command `Start-MigrationBatch <Migration Request Name>` to continue the migration of public folders and see if there is any difference.

Comment: This command worked. But, I've found more issues, but only one at a time. Is there a way to scan all folders and generate a report with all of the problem folders?

Comment: The above error usually is caused by an invalid alias format, if there is a small number of public folders, I think you could navigate to the PF management console and manually find/remove invalid characters, then restart the migration batch on your 2013 server. Besides, the related guide is for your reference: http://clintboessen.blogspot.com/2015/03/public-folder-migration-errorproperty.html